# Boyd & Vandenberghe, problem 2.10 — sublevel set of quadratic is convex

Tags: convex-analysis

Problem 2.10 of Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook):

---

Let $C \subseteq \Re^n$ be the solution set of a quadratic inequality, $$C = \left\{ x \in \Re^n \mid x^TAx +b^Tx + c \leq 0 \right\}$$ where $A \in \Re^{n \times n}$, b $\in \Re^n$ and c $\in \Re$. We want to show that $C$ is convex if $A \succeq 0$.

---

The solution is provided. But I want to prove it through another way in which we assume that if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are in the set then for $0\leq
\lambda\leq1$ the point $\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2$ is also in the set.

I tried it and I end up with following equation $$\lambda^2x_1^TAx_1+\lambda x_1^TAx_2-\lambda^2 x_1^TAx_2+\lambda x_2^TAx_1-\lambda^2 x_2^TAx_1+(1-\lambda)^2x_2^TAx_2+b^T\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)b^Tx_2+c$$ I do not know how to show that the above quantity is less than or equal to zero. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Group the terms related to the affine part and those related to the quadratic part. Then use the fact that $A \geq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(x)=x^TAx+b^Tx+c$ and $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=1$ then I think

$$
f(\lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2x_2) = \lambda_1f(x_1)+\lambda_2f(x_2)-\lambda_1\lambda_2(x_1-x_2)^TA(x_1-x_2)
$$

Comment: how can you not have a term with $\lambda_1^2$?

Comment: @LinAlg On the right-hand side $x_1^TAx_1$ appears with coefficient $\lambda_1-\lambda_1\lambda_2=\lambda_1^2$. And I implicitly assumed $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think even if we do not assume $A$ to be symmetric the right side of your equation matches perfectly with my equation. But I do not know which steps you took to obtain the right side of your equation from my equation.

Comment: @FrankMoses I just tied to group the terms the best I could.