# Boyd & Vandenberghe, problem 2.10 — is my solution correct?

Tags: solution-verification, convex-analysis

I'm doing problem 2.10 in textbook *Convex Optimization* by Boyd and Vandenberghe:

[image]

> Let $C \subseteq \mathbf{R}^{n}$ be the solution set of a quadratic inequality,
>
> $$
> C=\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid x^{T} A x+b^{T} x+c \leq 0\right\} \\
> $$
>
> with $A \in \mathbb{S}^{n}, b \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $c \in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> (a) Show that $C$ is convex if $A \succeq 0$.
>
> (b) Show that the intersection of $C$ and the hyperplane defined by $g^{T} x+h=0$ (where $g \neq 0)$ is convex if $A+\lambda g g^{T} \succeq 0$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

Could you please verify if my solution for part (b) is correct?

---

Let $B = A+\lambda g g^{T}$. Then $A = B - \lambda g g^{T}$ and thus

$$
\begin{aligned}
x^{T} A x+b^{T} x+c \leq 0 & \iff x^{T} (B - \lambda g g^{T}) x + b^{T} x+c \leq 0 \\
& \iff x^{T} B x - \lambda x^T g g^{T} x + b^{T} x+c \leq 0 \\
& \iff x^{T} B x - \lambda (g^T x)^T (g^{T} x) + b^{T} x+c \leq 0 \\
& \iff x^{T} B x - \lambda h^2 + b^{T} x+c \leq 0 \\
& \iff x^{T} B x  + b^{T} x+(c - \lambda h^2) \leq 0
\end{aligned}
$$

We have $B \succeq 0$ and is symmetric. Then it follows from (a) that $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid x^{T} B x  + b^{T} x+(c - \lambda h^2) \leq 0 \}$ is convex. Moreover $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid g^{T} x+h=0\}$ is convex. Then the result follows as the intersection of convex sets is convex.

Comment: @LinAlg I think that $h$ is given and fixed. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: You are right, I did not see $h$ was used in $g^Tx + h = 0$. The proof is correct.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2766163/339790)