# Boyd & Vandenberghe, problem 2.10 — is $A \in \mathbb S^n$ redundant?

Tags: matrices, solution-verification, proof-explanation, convex-analysis, symmetric-matrices

I'm doing part (a) problem 2.10 in textbook [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook) by Boyd and Vandenberghe:

[image]

> Let $C \subseteq \mathbf{R}^{n}$ be the solution set of a quadratic inequality,
>
> $$
> C=\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid x^{T} A x+b^{T} x+c \leq 0\right\} \\
> $$
>
> with $A \in \mathbb{S}^{n}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $c \in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> (a) Show that $C$ is convex if $A \succeq 0$.

In my attempt, I show that $C$ is convex without using the symmetry of $A$. Could you please verify if it's correct? I'm not sure why the authors include the assumption that $A \in \mathbb S^n$?

---

Let $f(x) = x^T A x + b^T x +c$. Then $\nabla^2 f(x) = A+A^T$ and $C = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}  \mid f(x) \le 0 \}$. Because $A\succeq 0$, so is $A^T\succeq 0$. As such, $\nabla^2 f(x) \succeq 0$. Finally, $f$ is convex. We need to prove $C$ is convex.

Let $x, y \in C$ and $\theta \in [0,1]$. Because $f$ is convex, $f(\theta x + (1-\theta)y) \le \theta f(x) + (1-\theta) f(y) \le 0$ as $f(x), f(y) \le 0$ and $\theta, 1-\theta \ge 0$. It follows that $\theta x + (1-\theta)y \in C$ and thus $C$ is convex.

Comment: You can assume without loss of generality that $A\in\mathbb{S}^n$, because it can always be decomposed into symmetric/skew-symmetric parts. A quadratic form of a skew symmetric part is always 0. In fact, your Hessian is exactly the symmetric part, scaled by 2. In other words, your proof is correct :)

Comment: @bodil: That sounds like an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1964244/339790

Comment: @PeterO. If you want me to post it as an answer then I will, however I figured the question doesn't warrant an answer, since it is just homework check, and similar questions have been asked multiple times.

Comment: [Sister question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4024681/339790).